# python-gssapi Credential error

Tags: python, kerberos, spnego

I am writing a small python application that uses the python-gssapi module. I am having issues however when creating a Credential object. Rhe error I am getting is:

```
gssapi.error.NoCredential: (458752)  No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible..
```

I have called `kinit` for `user1@somedomain.com` and obtained a TGT from AD. In my python code I then call:

```
clientGssCreds = creds.Credential(gssUserName, lifetime=gssapi.C_INDEFINITE, desired_mechs=oid_set, usage=gssapi.C_INITIATE)
```

where `gssUsername` is a Name defined by:

```
gssUserName = Name("user1@somedomain.com", gssapi.C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT** (script below):

```
 def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("username", help="user@domain.COM")
    parser.add_argument("target_server_spn", help="HTTP@serviceurl.com@domain.COM")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    krb5MechOid =  oids.OID.mech_from_string("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2")
    spnegoMechOid = oids.OID.mech_from_string("1.3.6.1.5.5.2")

    oid_set = oids.MutableOIDSet()
    oid_set.add(spnegoMechOid)
    oid_set.add(krb5MechOid)

    gssUserName = Name(args.username, gssapi.C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE)

    clientGssCreds = creds.Credential(gssUserName, lifetime=gssapi.C_INDEFINITE, desired_mechs=oid_set, usage=gssapi.C_INITIATE)

    gssServerName = gssapi.Name(args.target_server_spn, gssapi.C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE)
    clientContext = ctx.InitContext(gssServerName, clientGssCreds)
```

Comment: Can you post the full script?

Comment: Try editing your script above as port the question. Any python appropriate indenting you can do to prevent things from scrolling sideways would be a bonus.

Comment: removed my non-answer

Comment: So I think i've narrowed down the user and a property might need to be set to allow the underlying mechanism to obtain credentials. in java it is set by setting System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false"); Anyone know how to do the equivalent in python?

Comment: Were you able to determine this from the AD logs? Is there anything you can do to get more information from the server about your attempts to connect using python? (increasing verboseness *e.g.*) .

Comment: No, but I did a test using the Java jgss with essentially the same code. When i have the userSubjectCredsOnly flag set to false in Java I can authenticate correctly. When it is set to true I get the same error as my python program

Comment: Do any envars work on the client side (e.g. for logging I think there is one called `KRB5_TRACE` ... can't recall exactly those for setting client options). One guess is that python-gssapi uses the kerberos client configuration file `krb5.conf` for some settings (forwarding, address-free creds `etc.`) but it seems the cffi bits draw things straight out the GSSAPI headers (?).  You might be able to figure out the flag to set by looking in `gssapi.h` for something like `gssapi.C_NT_{WHO_KNOWS_WHAT}`. Overall, it sounds like a mailing list or bug report issue for the `python-gssapi` devs.